# Itunes app upload error

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, xcode8, itunes-store

I'm facing problem while uploading the app to itunes store i.e
 ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support." ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."

I have tried everything i.e Changed Architectures to

Standard architectures(armv7,arm64) -$(ARCHS_STANDARD)

Vaild Architectures

armv7 armv64 armv7s

Bulid Active Architecture only

No

[image]

[image]

can anyboady please help I'm stuck from last two days.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods? Please ensure their architectures are set properly as well

Comment: no I'm using any cocoapods.

Comment: Are you using any framework or library in your project? what is versions of Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

- You have the following 4 things:
- Architectures set to Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
- Base SDK set to some iOS8 SDK, for example Latest iOS (iOS 8.3) or iOS 8.3
- Build Active Architecture Only --> Release set to No
- Valid Architectures set to arm64 armv7 armv7s

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem is with one of the dependencies i.e RESTKIT(which have multiple targets in it) used for parsing the XML response.So what I did was simply added the library pointing to latest version and copied all my resources,files to a new project.It took some time but it was last option left for me as none of the above mention solutions worked for me.

Anyways, thanks for suggestions